# ionic e woocommerce api error 401

Tags: ionic3, woocommerce

estou tentando fazer uma conexão com woocommerce com ionicV3:

```js
this.wooCommerce = WC({
      url: 'http://localhost/WooComerce/',
      consumerKey: 'ck_933ad23a417a82e0de6d1558b917cb654d4d41d8',
      consumerSecret: 'cs_e82bae03c10dd8ebb4c3f29f3277ee1394d754d2',
    });
    this.wooCommerce.getAsync("products").then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("error =>" ,err);
    })
```

e estou com o seguinte error => Invalid object;
E essa é a requisição que estou fazendo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vê se esse link pode te ajudar : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/woocommerce-restapi/15947

Comment: eh nao ajudou muito não, o pior é que com o postman usando um sistema de Auth1.0 eu tenho acesso mais com o ionic nao